# kohana, can't load orm model

Tags: orm, model, kohana

I have problem saving data to database in Kohana using ORM. I am not an expert but i did more complex stuff than this. I guess the lack of basics lead to this.

I will add the model, form, and controller action code below. If anything else is needed you can ask. ps. This is my first time posting so I hope no rules are broken.

model:

```php
class Model_Polloptionvote extends ORM {
    protected $_table_name      = "poll_option_votes";
    protected $_primary_key     = "id";
    protected $_belongs_to = array(
        'option' => array(
            'model'  => 'polloption'
        )
    );

    protected $_table_columns = array(
        'id'        => array('type' => 'int'),
        'option_id' => array('type' => 'int'),
        'cookie'    => array('type' => 'string')
    );
}
```

form calling action:

```php
<form action="<?php echo Route::url("home", array(
    "controller"       => "polls",
    "action"           => "vote"
)); ?>" method="POST">      
    <?php
    if(isset($optionmodel)) {
        foreach ($optionmodel as $option) { ?>
            <label><?php
            echo Form::radio('option_id', $option->id, FALSE);
            echo $option->name; ?> </label> <?php 
            echo "</br>";
        }
    } ?>
    </br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="<?php echo __("Vote"); ?>" />
</form>
```

poll controler action:

```php
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Polls extends Controller_Base {

    public function action_vote() {

        $votemodel = ORM::factory("polloptionvote");
        $id = $this->request->post("option_id");
        if ($id != "") {
            $optionmodel = ORM::factory("polloption", $id);
            if ($votemodel->loaded()) {
                $votemodel->option_id = $id;
                $votemodel->cookie = "cookie";
                $votemodel->save(); 
            }

            $this->request->redirect(Route::url("home", array(
            "controller"    => "index"
            )));

        }
```

The view loads fine but it seems that `$votemodel->loaded()` is always false. If change that condition to `1==1` I get error. Probably because action doesn't know what to save where.

UPDATE AFTER LOOKING error.log:

error log:
    PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function route() on a non-object in /home/mywebsite/public_html/new/application/views/kohana/error.php on line 144

```
<?php if (Model_Korisnik::current() !== null) : ?>
              <ul>
                <li>Korisnik/ca: <span><?php echo Model_Korisnik::current()->username; ?></span></li>
                <li class="profile"><a href="<?php echo Route::url("viewUser", array(
                                "ignore"    => Model_Korisnik::current()->username,
                                "id"        => Model_Korisnik::current()->id
                            )); ?>" title="<?php echo __("Profile"); ?>"><?php echo __("Profile"); ?></a></li>
                <li class="settings"><a href="<?php echo Route::url("settingsURL"); ?>" title="<?php echo __("Settings"); ?>"><?php echo __("Settings"); ?></a></li>
                <li class="logout"><a href="<?php echo Route::url("auth", array(
                                "action"    => "logout"
                            )); ?>?redirect=<?php echo rawurlencode(Request::current()->route()->uri(Request::current()->param()) . URL::query()); ?>" title="<?php echo __("Log out"); ?>"><?php echo __("Log out"); ?></a></li>
              </ul>
          <?php else : ?>
```

Last line is 146

Comment: What do you expect here from `loaded()`? You are creating a new instance of this class, how can it already be loaded? And hwat error exactly do you get, when you remove that if?

Comment: The loaded() is just a test to see if instance is loaded, I would like to save the values $id and "cookie" to the table columns "option_id" and "cookie". If I leave out the if ($votemodel->loaded()) then I get error. I don't know where to see what is the error because I'm in a middle of someone else's website and I'm not expert in PHP or Kohana.

I am building a simple poll app here and the funny thing is the administration part is all done and working, but I can't get to save votes.

Comment: OK I think now I understand what you said. I'll remove the if condition and try to figure it out. Maybe I already solved the problem but this if(loaded()) stoped me from saving to db. Thanks.

Comment: Logs are usually in APPPATH/logs/ ;)

Comment: Updated problem because I can't post code here.

Comment: A little update, if I remove the line     $votemodel->save(); no error occurs.